# Vectorizing a custom parsing function gives a ValueError

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I've written a custom number parsing function. Basically, I want to convert app size information as it is given in the Google Play store (5.6M, 3M, 112K) to a standard float number.

To apply this function to a column of data in my data frame, I want to vectorize it using numpy.vectorize. However, when I'm testing it, i'm getting an error.

This is the function:

```
import numpy as np
import re

def parse_numbers(x, homo = False):
    if homo == False:
        if bool(re.match("^[0-9.]+[Mm]{1}$", x)):
            new_number = float(re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", x))
            return new_number * 1000000
        elif bool(re.match("^[0-9.]+[Kk]{1}$", x)):
            new_number = float(re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", x))
            return new_number * 1000
        else:
            return(x)
    elif homo == True:
        if bool(re.match("^[0-9.]+[MmKk]{1}$", x)):
            return "parsed_number"
        else:
            return(x)
    else:
        return "invalid setting for homo attribute"
```

As you can see, if it receives any input that can not be parsed as a number, it returns the original input.

When I test this manually, it works fine: `parse_numbers("3.1M")` returns `3100000` and `parse_numbers("not a number")` returns `not a number`.

Now I try to vectorize the function, and I test it like this:

```
vparse_numbers = np.vectorize(parse_numbers)
vparse_numbers(["3.1M", "2k", "not a number"])
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_27076/2263610390.py in <module>
     21 
     22 vparse_numbers = np.vectorize(parse_numbers)
---> 23 vparse_numbers(["3.0M", "2k", "not a number"])

c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2161             vargs.extend([kwargs[_n] for _n in names])
   2162 
-> 2163         return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
   2164 
   2165     def _get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args):

c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in _vectorize_call(self, func, args)
   2247 
   2248             if ufunc.nout == 1:
-> 2249                 res = asanyarray(outputs, dtype=otypes[0])
   2250             else:
   2251                 res = tuple([asanyarray(x, dtype=t)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'not a number'
```

When I test it using only the parseable numbers: `vparse_numbers(["3.1M", "2k", "not a number"])` it does return a list of the correct numbers to me.

What am I missing here? Am I not using the numpy.vectorize function correctly?

Comment: Why `np.vectorize`?  Reread its docs, including notes and disclaimers.  Why not a list comprehension?

Comment: From np.vectorize docs: "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."

Comment: Convenience is what i'm looking for. Why is that not good?

Comment: You want a mix of numbers and strings, right?  Shouldn't that be a list?

Comment: use normal `df.apply(parse_numbers)`. `numpy` will create `numpy.array` which can't mix different type of data (`string` and `float`). With `numpy.array` you would have to return `np.NaN` instead of `strings`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.vectorize` creates `numpy.array` which can't mix different type of data - `string` and `float` - and it tries to convert all to `float`. You would have to return `np.NaN` instead of all strings.

```
import numpy as np
import re
import pandas as pd

def parse_numbers(text, homo=False):
    if homo == False:
        if bool(re.match("^[0-9.]+[Mm]{1}$", text)):
            new_number = float(re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", text))
            return new_number * 1_000_000
        elif bool(re.match("^[0-9.]+[Kk]{1}$", text)):
            new_number = float(re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", text))
            return new_number * 1_000
        else:
            return np.NaN
    elif homo == True:
        if bool(re.match("^[0-9.]+[MmKk]{1}$", text)):
            return "parsed_number"
        else:
            return np.NaN
    else:
        raise Exception(f"invalid setting for homo attribute: {homo}")

vparse_numbers = np.vectorize(parse_numbers)
vparse_numbers(["3.1M", "2k", "not a number"])
```

But if you want to use `DataFrame` then you should use `.apply()` and it can return different type of data.

```
import numpy as np
import re
import pandas as pd

def parse_numbers(text, homo=False):
    if homo == False:
        if bool(re.match("^[0-9.]+[Mm]{1}$", text)):
            new_number = float(re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", text))
            return new_number * 1_000_000
        elif bool(re.match("^[0-9.]+[Kk]{1}$", text)):
            new_number = float(re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", text))
            return new_number * 1_000
        else:
            return text  # np.NaN
    elif homo == True:
        if bool(re.match("^[0-9.]+[MmKk]{1}$", text)):
            return "parsed_number"
        else:
            return text  # np.NaN
    else:
        raise Exception(f"invalid setting for homo attribute: {homo}")

df = pd.DataFrame({"test": ["3.1M", "2k", "not a number"]})

df['result'] = df['test'].apply(parse_numbers)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
           test        result
0          3.1M     3100000.0
1            2k        2000.0
2  not a number  not a number
```

---

**EDIT:**

I would write `parse_numbers` little different

- with `re` in only one line.
- using `{,1}` to convert to number also strings like `"123"`
- converting to `integer` at the end
- using name `parse_number` without `s` because it parses only one number.

```
import re
import pandas as pd


def parse_number(text, homo=False):
    if not isinstance(homo, bool):
        raise Exception(f"invalid setting for homo attribute: {homo}")

    results = re.findall("^([0-9.]+)([MmKk]{,1})$", text)
    #print(results)

    if results:
        if homo:
            return "parsed_number"
        else:
            number, name = results[0]
            new_number = float(number)
            if name in ('M', 'm'):
                new_number *= 1_000_000
            elif name in ('K', 'k'):
                new_number *= 1_000
            return int(new_number)
    else:
        return text  # np.NaN

        
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "test": ["3.1M", "2k", "123", "not a number"]
})

df['result'] = df['test'].apply(parse_number)
df['homo'] = df['test'].apply(lambda x:parse_number(x, True))

print(df)
```

Result:

```
           test        result           homo
0          3.1M       3100000  parsed_number
1            2k          2000  parsed_number
2           123           123  parsed_number
3  not a number  not a number   not a number
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [475]: alist = ["3.1M", "2k", "not a number"]
```

The straightforward application of your function to elements of the list:

```
In [476]: [parse_numbers(s) for s in alist]
Out[476]: [3100000.0, 2000.0, 'not a number']
```

`np.vectorize` will work if you specify the right otypes:

```
In [478]: fn = np.vectorize(parse_numbers, otypes=[object])
In [479]: fn(alist)
Out[479]: array([3100000.0, 2000.0, 'not a number'], dtype=object)


In [480]: timeit [parse_numbers(s) for s in alist]
12.9 µs ± 51.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [481]: timeit fn(alist)
24.1 µs ± 33.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

for returning objects, `frompyfunc` is a bit faster, without some of `np.vectorize` overhead:

```
In [482]: fn = np.frompyfunc(parse_numbers, 1,1)
In [483]: fn(alist)
Out[483]: array([3100000.0, 2000.0, 'not a number'], dtype=object)
In [484]: timeit fn(alist)
21.1 µs ± 68.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

My observation from other SO is that `pandas` `apply` is much slower.  `pandas` does a lot of extra work in tracking indices.

For a task that's basically string and list oriented, using `numpy` offers few, if any, advantages.

For a much larger list, the timing differences disappear:

```
In [485]: alist = alist*1000
In [486]: len(alist)
Out[486]: 3000
In [487]: timeit fn(alist)
12.5 ms ± 70.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [488]: timeit [parse_numbers(s) for s in alist]
12.3 ms ± 319 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [489]: fn = np.vectorize(parse_numbers, otypes=[object])
In [490]: timeit fn(alist)
12.1 ms ± 42.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```